# How to define package examples that reference an S4 class in another package

Tags: r, package, r-s4, roxygen2, roxygen

I am building a package that extends the functionality of another package, `crmPack`.  `crmPack` uses S4 classes.  I'm using `roxygen` to document my new package.  I'm getting an error when running `devtools::check()` on my new package:

```
> checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘crmreporter-Ex.R’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:

  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: summariseIncrementsRule
  > ### Title: Create a Tibble Describing an Increments Rule
  > ### Aliases: summariseIncrementsRule
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > if (requireNamespace("crmPack")) {
  +   inc <- IncrementsRelative(intervals=c(0, 20), increments=c(1, 0.33))
  +   summariseIncrementsRule("inc")
  + }
  Error in IncrementsRelative(intervals = c(0, 20), increments = c(1, 0.33)) : 
    could not find function "IncrementsRelative"
  Execution halted
```

Here's the relevant section of the `roxygen` comments and the definition of the generic in question:

```
#' @examples
#' if (requireNamespace("crmPack")) {
#'   inc <- IncrementsRelative(intervals=c(0, 20), increments=c(1, 0.33))
#'   summariseIncrementsRule(inc)
#' }
#' @import crmPack
#' @importFrom methods .valueClassTest
#' @export
setGeneric("summariseIncrementsRule", valueClass = "tbl", function(object) {
  standardGeneric("summariseIncrementsRule")
})
```

I have also tried

```
#' @importFrom crmPack IncrementsRelative
```

in the `roxygen` comments for the generic, with the same result.

`crmPack` appears in the `Imports:` section of my DESCRIPTION file and my NAMSEPACE file includes `import(crmPack)`.

How should I document my generic so that its example runs correctly?  [Which it does when run from the console.]

Comment: did you try to use `crmPack::IncremensRelative` to be sure the function can really not be found in crmPack?

Comment: Yes I did.  At the command line.  It worked.  But your comment gave me the idea of using `x <- crmPack::IncrementsRelative(...)` in the `roxygen` comment, and that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Waldi's question, I tried:

```
#' @examples
#' if (requireNamespace("crmPack")) {
#'   inc <- crmPack::IncrementsRelative(intervals=c(0, 20), increments=c(1, 0.33))
#'   summariseIncrementsRule(inc)
#' }
```

And this ran without error.  I was also able to remove `#' @import crmPack` from the `roxygen` comments, but removing `#' @importFrom methods .valueClassTest` caused `devtools::check()` to issue a warning.

Comment: OK, this is clear : if you want to make crmPack functions available for other users of your package (and also examples), you should export them as you do with your own functions.